# Erro ao carregar dados de uma listview em uma texbox c# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou desenvolvendo meu projeto em `Windows forms`, onde na aba cadastro mostra um form que possui uma `listview` com alguns dados do cliente, e ao lado vários `texbox` para cadastrar, alterar, visualizar ou excluir este cliente. Já possuo alguns clientes cadastrados, consigo visualizar no `listbox`. Porém, precisava que ao dar um duplo clique na linha, o sistema pegasse o ID dessa linha (Que é um item do listview), passasse para o banco de dados e carregasse todas as informações desse codigoID. Seria possivel? como fazer?

Até o momento consegui carregar os dados pelo nome completo do cliente, porém, para facilitar, o ideal seria dando um duplo clique na linha desejada.

Minha classe de banco de dados:

```
   public Cliente Buscar(string nome)
        {
            Cliente oCliente = new Cliente();
            using (MySqlConnection conexao = ConexaoBD.getInstancia().getConexao())
            {
                try
                {
                    conexao.Open();
                    MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand();
                    comando = conexao.CreateCommand();


                    comando.CommandText = "select * from cliente where nome  = @nome;";
                    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("nome", nome).ToString();
                    MySqlDataReader reader = comando.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        //Objeto Cliente
                        oCliente.ClienteID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ClienteID"].ToString());
                        oCliente.Nome = reader["Nome"].ToString();
                        oCliente.CpfCnpj = reader["CpfCnpj"].ToString();
                        oCliente.Telefone = reader["Telefone"].ToString();
                        oCliente.Rua = reader["Rua"].ToString();
                        oCliente.Numero = reader["Numero"].ToString();
                        oCliente.Bairro = reader["Bairro"].ToString();
                        oCliente.Cidade = reader["Cidade"].ToString();
                        if (reader["Observacao"] != null)
                            oCliente.Observacao = reader["Observacao"].ToString();
                        oCliente.Limite = reader["Limite"].ToString();
                        oCliente.UsuarioID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["UsuarioID"].ToString());
                        oCliente.DataAlteracao = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["DataAltercao"].ToString());
                        if (reader["Complemento"] != null)
                            oCliente.Complemento = reader["Complemento"].ToString();
                    }
                }
                catch (MySqlException ex)
                {
                    throw new System.Exception(ex.ToString());
                }
                finally
                {
                    conexao.Close();
                }
            }
            return oCliente;
        }
```

e chamando no forms

```
private void Txt_NomeCliente_Validating_1(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        //Verifica se está vazio
        if (txt_NomeCliente.Text.Trim().Equals(string.Empty))
            return;
        var oCliente = new ClienteNG().Buscar(txt_NomeCliente.Text.Trim());
        if (oCliente == null)
        {
            bt_Excluir.Enabled = false;
            return;
        }
    }

    public void Confirmar()
    {
        Txt_NomeCliente_Validating_1(txt_NomeCliente, new CancelEventArgs());

        if (lvl_ListagemClientes.SelectedIndices.Count <= 0)
            return;
        var oCliente = new ClienteNG().Buscar(txt_NomeCliente.Text.Trim());
        var iSelectedIndex = Convert.ToInt32(lvl_ListagemClientes.SelectedIndices[0]);
        if (iSelectedIndex >= 0)
        {
            iRetorno = Convert.ToInt32(lvl_ListagemClientes.Items[iSelectedIndex].Text);
            txt_CodigoCliente.Text = Convert.ToInt32(oCliente.ClienteID).ToString();
            txt_cpfcnpj.Text = oCliente.CpfCnpj;
            mkd_Telefone.Text = oCliente.Telefone;
            txt_Rua.Text = oCliente.Rua;
            txt_Numero.Text = oCliente.Numero;
            cb_Bairro.Text = oCliente.Bairro;
            cb_Cidade.Text = oCliente.Cidade;
            tb_Observacoes.Text = oCliente.Observacao;
            mkd_LimiteTotal.Text = oCliente.Limite;
            label.Text = oCliente.Complemento;
            ////////////////////// Nao esta aparecendo os campos de dados
        }
    }

    private void Lvl_ListagemClientes_DoubleClick_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Confirmar();
    }
```

Comment: Explicando de uma forma mais clara, no meu código ao escrever o nome do cliente no textbox, pesquisar, e dar um duplo click no listview no cliente pesquisado, ele carrega as informações do textbox. Só que para isso acontecer, o nome tem que estar igual ao nome salvo no banco de dados. Meu objetivo é não carregar os dados pelo nome digitado no textbox e sim somente pelo duplo click na listview, para isso, ele precisaria pegar o primeiro dado informado na linha do listview que é o Código do cliente, e pesquisar no banco por esse código. Assim, mostrando as informações do cliente pelo código

Comment: A ideia seria então exibir todos os clientes cadastrados no ListView, e então carregar nos TextBox os dados do cliente quando ocorresse um duplo-clique?